# How to get the stream response of my HttpResponseMessage in c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, binaryreader, httpresponsemessage

I am working with **HttpClient** and I want to get the stream response.
I want to make it work like `Webresponse.getResponseStream()` in order to read it in a **BinaryReader** like this :

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new BufferedStream(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

I have tried to use the `GetStreamAsync`, but it never works because I am forced to use await and the **HttpResponseMessage** gets bytes infinitely.

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new BufferedStream(await myHttpClient.GetStreamAsync());
```

I don't know how to use the **CopyToAsync**, so I don't know if it works..
Any idea ?

**Edit : More details.**
The method `getStreamAsync` works when I'm receiving **one anwser**, but since i'm receiving a **live stream**, I don't get the stream before the live ends !

Comment: Forced to use `await`? Sounds like you don't understand how async code works. How do you call the async function that this code is contained in?

Comment: Probably not.. But I get error on the line without await. The method is called with await aswell. Edit : Error = can't convert Task<Stream> to Stream

Comment: Is the method you are using this in Async ?

Comment: `public async Task myMethod(){... BinaryReader...}`

Comment: @SamuelL. Why don't you want to use await?  If you want to utilize `HttpResponseMessage` to get stream you can try `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result`

Comment: Because it waits for the anwser, but the stream is receiving informations continually, so I never get the stream.

Comment: @SamuelL. You can get all the stream after the await method. Or you can use `Result` to access it.

Comment: The issue is there actually : I never get the result probably because it is always receiving data, and I need to get this stream in order to read these data

Comment: According to ms docs `The returned Task<TResult> object will complete after the response headers are read`. So the task doesn't wait for stream completion. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You should use `await` to get the stream. Does reading from `BinaryReader` work in the 2nd example?